# How can i get correct className from multiple classes in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, classname

I have a parent element with a single child element. I would like to get return only the parent element's classname based on its classname. That means now in the console log, i getting 3 classes. But only want 'one' here. Because the 'parent' variable is targetted the class '.one'. Hopes someone can help me on this. If you did'nt understand ask me, so that i'll come up with more details. Thanks in advance.

```js
let parent = document.querySelector(".one");
let correctClass = parent.className;
console.log(correctClass);
```

```html
<div class="one two three">
<div class="child-element">Child Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you know the className that you want to get why do you want to get the class name from element?

Comment: Just hardcode `console.log("one")`?

Comment: @Yadab this code is for another purpose where i need this functionality. Means i need to detect the same class of parent element. I come up with this code to reduce confusions.

Answer (score 1):

No need to access the element at all when you already know the selector:

```js
const selector = ".one";
const parent = document.querySelector(selector);
const correctClass = selector.slice(1);
console.log(correctClass, parent);
```

```html
<div class="one two three">
<div class="child-element">Child Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually my code is the use with a class object. So the selector '.one' is actually referng using a this variable. That means the '.one' is actually hold by `this.parent`. When i console "this.parent" i get all the element. That is why i used className. But then i get other classes along with one. So i need to check the parent class has the string 'one' in it. Hopes you understood.

Comment: @RenJitsm Maybe [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70210912/edit) to include the actual code. But it's still really unclear: if you already do know the class name that you want to get as a result, why are you trying to compute it somehow?

Comment: "*i need to check the parent class has the string 'one' in it.*" - that's a very different question, but can be achieved using [`parent.classList.contains('one')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which returns a boolean, not a class name.

Comment: Bergi, you are correct, the explanation is confusing due to my poor english, but you are almost near of the solution. Let me do something as per your last comment. Thanks for the update.